# Bootstrap issue with displaying label and layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have utilised bootstrap 3 horizontal forms. I also have been using the jquery validator plugin to validate my forms. When I try display a tick image next to my input field. it continually goes underneath it. I have applied the .valid class which consists of the tick image to display: inline-block, although I am still not getting any results. This is my valid class which appends if a input field is valid. This is my form-group class

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-lg-3" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <sf:input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" path="email" /><br/><sf:errors path="email" cssClass="error"></sf:errors>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my css '.valid' field which displays after a input field is valid.

```
label.valid{
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background: url(../img/Done.png) center center no-repeat;
      display: inline-block;
      text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

This is an image of what I am getting:
[image]
As you can see the label is displayed under the input field. I would like to display it directly next to it. Please help

Comment: There is no place after the input, it's responsive, you add an element after... I think you should reduce the input width. Can you with your navigator inspector, reduce the input width and see if the done.png go to align right ?

Comment: Even if I reduce the size of the input field, it still does not change anything.

Comment: Can you post the generated html too please ?

Comment: What do you mean by generated html sorry?

Comment: the final html, in your navigator.

Comment: @Jahnux73 I have added a new screen shot of where the label field is generated. Is this what you mean?

Comment: can u chek this css` {
            display: inline-block;
            width: auto;
            margin: 0px 5px;
            vertical-align: text-top;
           }`

Comment: @Deekey is that to my label.valid class? What about the img?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please apply this CSS and Check

```
.addthiscSS{
    display:inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: text-top;
   }
```

Comment: @Matthew Bobrowski this CSS add to the label

Comment: I tired this. Still nothing.

Comment: @Matthew Bobrowski okeytry to give that css to text Box and reduce its width

Comment: Yeah I agree, probably something very small

Answer (score 0):

class form-control sets the width to 100%

Try this setup.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-lg-3 text-right">
      <label class="control-label" for="email">Email:</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">
      <sf:input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" path="email" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3">
      <sf:errors path="email" cssClass="error"></sf:errors>
   </div>
</div>
```